# how to convert WPS office word,excel file to PDF using ABCPdf

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf-generation, abcpdf

how to convert the WPS Office Word document to pdf ,excel to pdf,ppt to pdf
 using ABC PDFin dot net.

I try it from documentation [Can ABCpdf convert my Microsoft Office documents to PDF?](http://www.websupergoo.com/support.htm)

please any one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From section 6.1 of the link in the question:

> To convert Office documents ABCpdf .NET requires either [WordGlue .NET](http://www.websupergoo.com/wordglue-1.htm), or the use of MS Office or OpenOffice.org as helper applications. We would recommend you use the current versions, which must be installed on the same system as ABCpdf.

So, ABCpdf on its own: Not possible.